# Find out private ip when using node / socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Currently my socket.io chat app only allows 1 user per ip, which means if two people in the same house or net want to use the chat, only one of them will be able to.

Is there a way to find out what private ip a user has, besides it's public ip which i already know?

Comment: presumably they would all be coming through a single gateway.  Without running code in client, I think you are going to be hard pressed to figure out the IP of the machine they are on.  That said... your users on a virtual machine environment?  Are you asking for the HOST ip in that scenario?  I didn't down vote you - but you could be more explicit about your needs and post the code you do have..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your chat app is Javascript that runs in a browser, then **"No"**, there is no way for your server to know what the private IP address is of the end-user.  If your chat app was a native app, then your native chat app could fetch the local private IP address and send it to the server.  But, that can't be done from a browse without native code plug-ins.

The browser does not provide a way for Javascript to obtain the private IP address so there is no way for your chat app to send it to your server.  And, there is certainly no way for the server to know the private IP address all by itself.

You can use cookies to detect multiple chat windows in the same browser open at once (cookie the first connection, then look for any other incoming connections with the same cookie).  But, you cannot prevent multiple browsers using that scheme.

The usual way to deal with this is to require an account and login to that account and enforce only one login per account at a time and to require unique email addresses or even verified credit card numbers per account to discourage people making lots of accounts.  Of course, there are still ways around this too (multiple email boxes or multiple credit cards), but it's enough of an obstacle to stop many and prevent large scale abuse.  In general, you should design your service so if someone does this, it frankly isn't a problem.